# How to visualize a cylinder 3d data in rgl R?

Tags: 3d, visualization, rgl

I have a 3D (xyz) data of a cylinder from a laser scanner.Containing 201716 points.

```
x          y        z
-114.63    62.23    0.004
-114.748   62.297   0.061
-114.55    62.246   -0.046
-114.66    62.308   0.009
-114.744   62.356   0.068
-114.815   63.306   -0.017
-114.579   63.319   -0.104
-114.686   63.381   -0.048
-114.78    63.435   0.009
-98.459    59.892   2.489
-98.353    59.834   2.636
-98.323    59.881   2.954
-98.303    59.872   3.005
-98.281    59.86    3.053
-99.868    60.922   3.562
-100.037   61.053   4.284
-98.326    60.005   2.931
-98.33     60.009   2.981
-98.351    60.023   3.032
-98.286    59.988   3.13
-99.844    60.953   3.537
```

How can i visualize this 3D data using rgl in R?

Answer (score 0):

Put the data into a matrix `d`, with columns of x, y and z coordinates, and call `points3d(d)`.

If you know more about the structure of your data you can probably do better.  For example, you might be able to join pairs of points (using `segments3d(d)`) or triples of points (using `triangles3d(d)`.)  Both of those will look terrible if the data is not structured so that they make sense.

If you want to see a scale on the plot, finish by calling `decorate3d()` to add axes and scales.